# How to make Xcode work with VoiceOver?

Tags: mac, xcode, voiceover

I have tried Swift Playgrounds on iPad but that is useless as you never know where your character is.  I am trying to develop my first app in Xcode.

I use Swift 3.  How do you make Xcode Swift Playground work with VoiceOver on the Mac?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Your question about where to find tutorials is considered off-topic for this site.  I edited your question to remove that part so your question doesn't get closed.

Comment: [VoiceOver reading results of Swift Playground print statements in Xcode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/368161/voiceover-reading-results-of-swift-playground-print-statements-in-xcode?rq=1)